# Per Project User Access in Subversion

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I have repositories created in C:\Data\Subversion as well as sub-folders like C:\Data\Subversion\Dev-Mobile.

I can give per project access to users for the repos in the root folder without problems. For that I'm adding those lines in svn-acl:

```
[Project1:/]
Test = rw
```

However, I try to give access for a repo in a sub-folder but it doesn't work:

```
[Test161:/Dev-Mobile]
Test = rw
```

The project is declared in subversion.conf as:

```
<Location /Dev-Mobile/Test161>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath C:/Data/Subversion/Dev-Mobile/Test161
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Test161 Repository"
  AuthUserFile c:/Data/Subversion/svn-auth-file
  Require valid-user
  AuthzSVNAccessFile c:/Data/Subversion/svn-acl
</Location>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to add the subfolder in the path (after :/) since this was the logical thing to do but I've found out Subversion will automatically scan the subdirs.

So this is the correct sintex no matter if the repo is in the root or a subfolder!

```
[Test161:/]
Test = rw
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the syntax of the svn-acl file. But I think that the syntax

```
[Test161:/Dev-Mobile]
Test = rw
```

is meant for configuring the permissions of the sub-folder `/Dev-Mobile` of an *existing* repository `Test161`. That is, it seems you are getting the identification of the repository and the folder within the repository confused.